# Pass String[] from Android app to web service using HttpPost?

Tags: android, string, web-services, http-post

I was wondering if it is possible to pass a String[] to a web service which would accept this?  I have tried using NameValuePairs but only allows Strings.  Or should I scratch this idea and go with something else.  Would using SOAP/ksoap2 be possible?  Thanks!

Comment: Consider looking into something like JSON or defining your own protocol for transfering data across post messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say go with json. Lot less trouble than xml.

Comment: right. this is what I figured I might have to do...its more enjoyable :)

Comment: can you please mark my answer as the chosen answer... :o) thanks.

Comment: Here's a reasonable tutorial to start with. It uses org.json that comes with Android: 

http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/